# Angular 1.6.6 blocking my url sourcing to another project

Tags: angularjs

I have the following statement in my project (within Index.html)...

```
var amqApp = angular.module('amqApp', ['moment-picker'])
            .config([
                '$compileProvider', 'momentPickerProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider',
                function ($compileProvider, momentPickerProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {

                    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|stcall|chrome-extension):/);                                     

                    momentPickerProvider.options({
                        format: "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm a",
                        today: true
                    });

                    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
                        // Allow same origin resource loads.
                        'self',
                        // Allow loading from our assets domain. **.
                        'http://localhost*/**',
                        '*localhost*',
                        'http*',
                        '*54497*',
                        '**',
                        '*'

                    ]);

                }
            ]);
```

I am trying to allow the use of another project's javascript methods.  I have sourcing to the other project...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@(FayShared.FS.GetAppSetting("CommonServicesURL") + "/_shared/loan-search.directive.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@(FayShared.FS.GetAppSetting("CommonServicesURL") + "/_shared/commonService.js")"></script>
```

But I get a blocking error when I try to run this...

> angular-1.6.6.js:14700 Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: http://localhost:54497 / _shared / loan - search.directive.html
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$sce/insecurl?p0=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A54497%20%2F%20_shared%20%2F%20loan%20-%20search.directive.html

This used to work am I'm not sure why its not blocking my urls.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is angular on same url or port?

Comment: I'm running both projects locally.  They are on different ports, 50058 and 54497.

Comment: I think you need to add  http in $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist

Comment: I have that in the top of my module statement.  Am I doing the statement correctly?  Do I need to expand it?

Comment: Same error when I added http and http? to the aHrefSanitationWhitelist...                    
                    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|stcall|chrome-extension|http|http?):/);

Comment: I think you need to remove '?' After https because it checks https if it true then further condition will execute